# (Unity) Destroy a gameObject in the current scene and keep it permanently destroyed even after loading current scene?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do I destroy a gameObject permanently? That is, I want the gameObject to be there only once before if I destroy it in the current scene and then when I reload the same scene, I want it to be disabled/destroyed. How do I achieve this?

Edit: Or the below script can run only once with a bool variable?

```
void Update()
{
  if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A)
  {
    GameObject go = GameObject.Find("Cloner");
    Destroy(go);
    SceneManager.LoadScene("Home");
  }
}
```

Comment: how about setting a bool flag on your Gameobject, that is then checked by your Find Method. In Find you'll either return null if the flag is true (and therefore you wouldn't have access to the requested Game Object) or if the flag is false return the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it by using DontDestroyOnLoad() in the function

> void Awake()

```
static bool created = false;
public bool Loading = true;

void Awake()
{
  if(!created)
  {
    DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
    created = true;
  }
  else
  {
  Destroy(this.gameObject);
  }
}

void Update()
{
  if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A) && LoadingOnce == true)
  {
    GameObject go = GameObject.Find("Cloner");
    Destroy(go);
    LoadingOnce = false;
    SceneManager.LoadScene("Home");
  }
}
```

Comment: what does `DontDestroyOnLoad` have to do with it? the simple bool check should be enough

Comment: @derHugo I am reloading the scene which is why I need this script to be active.

Comment: I see that but it doesn't matter. The static bool is not affected by reloading the scene so simply setting it to true once and checking it to destroy the object should be enough ... I would do `void Awake(){ if(created) { Destroy (this.gameObject); }  created = true; }`

Comment: @derHugo ah okay I did not know about this. Thank you.